# Setting up C++ standard in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

ALL,

At work we are using Eclipse for C++.

I recently acquired a new laptop and had to install a newer (latest) Eclipse - version 2020-12 (4.18.0).

Now I need to set up a C++11 standard, but I can't find where do I do that.

Could someone please help?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

To change your C++ Standard: `Window -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> [compiler]`, where you select your `[compiler]` accordingly. Better change it for all the compilers. I would also recommend to use a more recent C++ standard, i.e. c++17, or c++20. Make sure to append the command `-std=c++xx` between `-dD` and `"${INPUTS}"`, where `xx` is your preferred c++ standard, i.e. 11, 17, 20, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install C++ software on Eclipse:

Launch Eclipse → Help → Install New Software → In "Work with" field, paste " [http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler"](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler%22)
In "Name" box, expand "Programming Language" node ⇒ Check "C/C++ Development Tools" ⇒ "Next" ⇒ ... ⇒ "Finish".
Then restart Eclipse and select new Project, click on "Other", there will be a C/C++ Folder in which you can start a new Project, you will find a C++ option inside it.

In addition, you can change the Eclipse perspective to a C++-friendly interface by clicking Window-> Perspective->Open perspective->Other->C++

If there is any further concern with this question please tell me.

Comment: I do have an Eclipse for C++. All I need is to set it up for C++11, i.e. set the `-std=c++11` option in order to index the project correctly.

Comment: The link points to the Eclipse Kepler update site which is more than 7 years old and 15 releases behind. That won't work with the current Eclipse and I doubt that anyone has missed updating for so many years.